# Dynamic submenu items with cursesmenu

Tags: python, menu, curses

I'm using Python's [curses-menu](https://github.com/pmbarrett314/curses-menu) package and understand how to make submenus in a menu when the menu is statically defined before `.show()` is called.  I am trying to make a menu item which, when selected, will dynamically make the selected submenu's items.  In other words, when I select an item, I want run code to, say, take some user input, and make something like a [`SelectMenu`](http://curses-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#getting-a-selection) with each string as an item.  Lastly, I then want to use the selected string as input to a function.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
# Import the necessary packages
from cursesmenu import *
from cursesmenu.items import *

def work_with_selection(selection):
    print('You selected {}'.format(selection))

def build_sub():
    items = []
    for i in range(3):
        item = input('Type an item: ')
        items.append(item)
    selection = SelectionMenu(items).get_selection(items)
    work_with_selection(selection)

# Create the menu
menu = CursesMenu("Title", "Subtitle")

# Create some items

# Dynamically build submenu
build_item = FunctionItem("Build dynamic submenu", build_sub)

menu.append_item(build_item)

# Finally, we call show to show the menu and allow the user to interact
menu.show()
```

It appears to work except that once I chose Exit from the submenu, the parent menu redraws, and the cursor keys stop working.  Instead of moving the selector, it give control-characters with letters as in the top left of this:

```
^[[B^[[A^[[B───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                          │
│ Title                                                                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                                                          │
│ Subtitle                                                                                                                                 │
│   1 - Build dynamic submenu                                                                                                              │
│   2 - Exit                                                                                                                               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
│   4 - Exit                                                                                                                               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I'm using Python 3.

Is using `SelectionMenu` the right way to go?  If so, how do I fix the parent main menu once I return to it?  If not, how should I make such a dynamic submenu creation?

Comment: I know it has been a while since you asked this (so you may not need it anymore), but why do you need to generate the submenu on the fly? I've been working with `curses-menu` recently, and coincidentally came across your question. I was able to get some dynamic behaviour by nesting `CursesMenu` objects in top-level `SubmenuItems`, then using `FunctionItem`s in the nested menus - but in my case I knew the menu structure in advance. Looking at the source, if you create a `MenuItem` that is both a `FunctionItem` and a `SubmenuItem`, you might be able to do what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks @J.B .  If i resume working on my curses project, I'll try your tips!  To answer Why: My main menu item will fetch an inventory of items.  I then want user to select an item from the inventory to drill down into more operations he can do with it (ie Order More, See Recent Sales, etc).  The inventory submenu is dynamic.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Since writing my first comment, I have actually moved away from `curses-menu`, and instead settled on `consolemenu`. It is directly derived from `curses-menu`, but removes the curses dependency. It's otherwise a direct drop-in replacement with a slightly different user interface, but IMO it has a few more features that make it generally more flexible. (Most importantly to me, it supported greater amounts of text in the menu much better). Unless you want that curses navigation style specifically, I'd recommend it! https://console-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/